# Screensaver in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, screensaver

I have a screensaver written in C# which takes a screenshot of the Desktop and displays it as the, guess what, screensaver.

This works pretty well except in Windows 8 where the screensaver launches in, what looks like, a separate Desktop with a solid background and thus i am only taking a screenshot of this solid background instead of the actual desktop.

This only counts if the screensaver is launched by the timeout by windows itself, not if you execute the screensaver directly (by double-clicking the *.scr) nor in the preview-panel (/p switch) or if you preview it using the "Test" button (which imho invokes the /s Switch).

According to a Moderator at Microsoft-Answer and so far the only information i found regarding this:

"A design change was made in Windows 8 that prevents screensavers from drawing over an image of the desktop." - Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/bubbles-screensaver-has-black-background/e0807324-5ca6-4abe-b6ba-716848b41ff5

tl;dr: I'm looking for a way to take a screenshot of the actual desktop through a screensaver in Windows 8.

Thanks in advanced.